# Bluetooth device dissapears

Tags: 22.04, bluetooth, realtek

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with a Realtek Bluetooth adapter. It all worked perfectly until a few days ago when the bluetooth device started to suddenly turn off and no longer being able to turn it back on.

I ran `dmesg -T` and this is the output:

```
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:04 2023] usb 3-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:05 2023] usb 3-2.1: reset high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:05 2023] usb 3-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:05 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:05 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:06 2023] usb 3-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:06 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:06 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:06 2023] usb 3-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:06 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:06 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 4, error -71
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:07 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:08 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:08 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:08 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:08 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:08 2023] usb 3-2-port3: attempt power cycle
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:09 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:09 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:09 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:09 2023] usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 7, error -71
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:09 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:09 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:10 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:10 2023] usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 8, error -71
[Mon Nov 13 11:01:10 2023] usb 3-2-port3: unable to enumerate USB device
```

On another blog post, somebody recommended to write the value `0` and then `1` to `cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/3-2.3/authorized` but the file was missing at the time.

Meanwhile, after a reboot the file was there with the contents `1`.

After the reboot, I ran `dmesg -T` again an this was the output:

```
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:56 2023] usb 3-2: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=05e3, idProduct=0608, bcdDevice=88.32
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] hub 3-2:1.0: USB hub found
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] hub 3-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.1: New USB device found, idVendor=30c9, idProduct=0013, bcdDevice= 0.01
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=1, SerialNumber=2
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.1: Product: HP TrueVision HD Camera
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.1: Manufacturer: DJKCVA1G4FVZLB
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.1: SerialNumber: 0001
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:57 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:58 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:58 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:58 2023] usb 3-2.3: device descriptor read/64, error -32
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:58 2023] usb 3-2-port3: attempt power cycle
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: Device not responding to setup address.
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: device not accepting address 6, error -71
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: new full-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=b00c, bcdDevice= 0.00
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[Mon Nov 13 11:45:59 2023] usb 3-2.3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
[Mon Nov 13 11:46:01 2023] usb 3-2.1: Found UVC 1.00 device HP TrueVision HD Camera (30c9:0013)
[Mon Nov 13 11:46:01 2023] input: HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2.1/3-2.1:1.0/input/input20
[Mon Nov 13 11:46:05 2023] input: Keyboard K380 Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:04:00.4/usb3/3-2/3-2.3/3-2.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:1/0005:046D:B342.0005/input/input22
```

I also need to mention that all other USB devices and Wi-Fi were working correctly, only bluetooth was affected.

What can I do to prevent this kind of issue?

Comment: Do you have many USB devices connected?

Comment: A webcam and a mouse. The laptop has 3 ports, two USB 3.1 and one USB-C. I only used the 3.1 ones.

Comment: See if disconnecting the webcam allows Bluetooth to work

Comment: I already tried that, doesn't seem to have any results. Only a reboot fixes the issue, but I am trying to avoid to do this every few hours.